# MDX - do no show contacts if the linked action is selected

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a model which contains a measuregroup with one row for every contacted "Person" for a specific "Action".

Now I want to have my dimension "Action" behave as follows:
I I select an "Action" only all "Persons" contacted may be shown that do NOT exist in that specific action.

Even if a "Person" exists in the selected "action" and in another "action" the "Person" may not be shown.

Comment: Did my answer help you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a potential pattern you could use. The 3rd set excludes all customers who bought `[Bottles and Cages]` and it is then used in the subsequent query.

```
WITH 
  SET [customers] AS 
    {
      [Customer].[Customer].&[15568]
     ,[Customer].[Customer].&[12067]
     ,[Customer].[Customer].&[21414]
     ,[Customer].[Customer].&[18695]
    } 
  SET [custWhoBoughtBottlesAndCages] AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
      [customers]
     ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Subcategory].[Bottles and Cages]
    ) 
  SET [custExcludeThoseWhoBoughtBottlesAndCages] AS 
    Except
    (
      [customers]
     ,[custWhoBoughtBottlesAndCages]
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    [Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory] ON 0
 ,[custExcludeThoseWhoBoughtBottlesAndCages] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount];
```